# Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema. - configuration.entry[0]

Tags: webpack, path, webpack-dev-server

I'm having issues running webpack-dev-server, the script is `npm run dev`.

- Here is my error message:

```
env: { WEBPACK_SERVE: true, '--mode': 'development' }
[webpack-cli] Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.entry[0] should be a non-empty string.
   -> A module that is loaded upon startup. Only the last one is exported.
```

- Here is my webpack.config.js

```
    const path = require('path');
    const config = (env) => {
      console.log('env:', env);
      return {
        mode: env['--mode'] || 'development',
        entry: {
          path: path.join(__dirname, './client/src/index.js')
        },
        output: {
          path: path.join(__dirname, './client/dist'),
          filename: 'bundle.js'
        },
        module: {
          rules: [
            {
              test: /\.js/,
              exclude: /nodeModules/,
              loader: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
              test: /\.(css|scss)\b/,
              use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
            },
          ]
        }
      }
    }
    
    
    module.exports = config;
```

- Here is my package.json

```
    {
      "name": "docscraper",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "test": "jest --watch",
        "server": "nodemon server/server.js",
        "start": "webpack --watch --env --mode=development",
        "dev": "webpack-dev-server --entry $npm_package_input_path --output-filename .$npm_package_output_path --env --mode=development",
        "build": "webpack --env --mode=production",
        "echo": "echo 'this is an echo'",
        "grep": "$npm_package_grep",
        "reset": "rm -r node_modules package-lock.json && npm install"
      },
      "keywords": [],
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
        "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.309.0",
        "aws-sdk": "^2.1353.0",
        "axios": "^1.3.5",
        "babel": "^6.23.0",
        "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
        "express": "^4.18.2",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.22",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "sass-loader": "^13.2.2",
        "webpack": "^5.78.0"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.21.4",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
        "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
        "css-loader": "^6.7.3",
        "jest": "^29.5.0",
        "sass": "^1.62.0",
        "style-loader": "^3.3.2",
        "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^4.13.3"
      },
      "config" :{
        "input_path": "/Users/{user}/{root}/client/src/index.js",
        "output_path": "/Users/{user}/{root}/client/dist/bundle.js",
        "grep": "grep -E -n --color \"\b[csc][a-zA-Z0-9_.]+@yahoo[a-zA-Z0-9._].[com|co]+\b\" ./__tests__/data/test.txt"
      }
    }
```

- Here is my project structure

```
    ./
    ├── __tests__
    │   ├── api.test.js
    │   ├── data
    │   │   ├── sorted.txt
    │   │   ├── test.txt
    │   │   └── test2.txt
    │   ├── fileToArray.test.js
    │   └── sort.test.js
    ├── client
    │   ├── dist
    │   │   ├── bundle.js
    │   │   ├── bundle.js.LICENSE.txt
    │   │   ├── index.html
    │   │   ├── styles.css
    │   │   └── styles.scss
    │   └── src
    │       ├── App.js
    │       ├── OptionModal.js
    │       ├── Options.js
    │       └── index.js
    ├── config.json
    ├── node_modules
    ├── package-lock.json
    ├── package.json
    ├── readme.md
    ├── server
    │   ├── controllers
    │   │   ├── AWS.js
    │   │   ├── grep.js
    │   │   └── sort.js
    │   ├── routes
    │   │   ├── getFiles.js
    │   │   ├── grepFiles.js
    │   │   └── test.js
    │   └── server.js
    └── webpack.config.js
```

Based on the error message, I thought it was an issue with the input path in my webpack.config.js, so I tried to pass the absolute path directly to the script via a variable but that didn't seem to fix it.

Comment: `configuration.entry[0]` suggests it's expecting an _array_, you've given an object.

Comment: So I changed config.entry into an array and now the dev server has started, but it can't find the output files...this is very odd. The .entry value has always been an object before...why would the config schema be different in this case?... I think it may have something to do with how I'm passing variables through my bash flags